# Тире и запятая

Tags: общие-вопросы

Пожалуйста, объясните пунктуацию в предложениях подобного рода. Нужна тут запятая/не нужна тут запятая. И почему. 
Мне вот кажется, что поясняющая часть входит в оборот "который", поэтому запятая ставится только одна, после конца поясняющей части (в данном случае это "любимом"). Но как правильно?

1) Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте, — нашем любимом — и постучал

2) Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте — нашем любимом, — и постучал.

3) Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте, — нашем любимом, — и постучал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно: Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте***,*** — нашем любимом — и постучал. Запятая закрывает придаточное предложение, а тире вводит добавочное сообщение- вставку. После вставки нет основания ставить запятую. В примере, который Вы приводите, поясняющая часть не может входить в оборот ''который''. Если перестроить предложение, она останется в первой части. Ср.: Я подошёл к нашему любимому дому,который стоял на старом месте. Предложение же: "Я подошёл к дому,который наш любимый", - некорректно. 
Подробнее здесь:

> [Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина //7. Знаки препинания при вводных и вставных конструкциях, §97](http://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/#id-7%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%C2%A797)
>
> [Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. Д.Э. Розенталь//РАЗДЕЛ 7 Знаки препинания при словах, грамматически не связанных с членами предложения, § 26.Вставные предложения и словосочетания.2](http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827510.html#id-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B7%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%81%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A726%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F2)

***Дополнение***

Третий Глаз, комментарии закончились, вынужден писать здесь.

> В примере ***"Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте — выжженном поле, — и постучал" - запятая действительно стоит на втором месте.*** Вставная конструкция, имеющая характер уточнения и выраженная причастным оборотом , примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части СПП и запятая ставится после всей конструкции.  подробнее об этом здесь:Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография. Пунктуация.

Comment: Серж:"Если перестроить предложение, она останется в первой части".===
По-моему, не останется. Ведь "нашем любимом" относится не к дому, а к месту: 
Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на нашем любимом, старом месте, и постучал.===
Я бы выбрал второй из предложенных Третьим глазом вариантов.

Comment: Если "наш любимый'' относится к месту, все равно запятая должна закрывать придаточную часть: Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте, — нашем любимом — и постучал.
В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте ''разрыва" основного предложения, помимо тире,могут быть еще запятые. Возможны следу-е случаи: 
**перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура первой части предложения: Он посмотрел на пепелище , которое окружало его, - какой ужас! - и руки бессильно опустились у него - запятая закрывает  придаточную часть СПП**.

Comment: А если бы второго сказуемого -- "и постучал" -- не было? От Вашей пунктуации  осталось бы это:
"Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте, — нашем любимом."===
Вас не смущает запятая плюс тире перед "нашем любимом"?

Comment: А в этом случае - только тире, запятая не нужна. Здесь уже не вставная конструкция, а пояснение. Хотя такое предложение небезупречно. Но теоретически - только тире. 
См.: Пояснительные конструкции. Розенталь. Д.Э. Справочник-практикум. Орфография. Пунктуация.

Comment: То есть в этом случае Вы считаете излишним закрывать придаточное? Это означает, что "пояснительная конструкция" относится всё-таки именно к придаточной части. И запятая, закрывающая придаточное в исходном предложении, должна была бы быть поставлена тогда не после слова "месте", а после "нашем любимом". ИМХО

Comment: Я считаю, что в приведенном вами примере:"Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте, — нашем любимом - запятая не должна быть. Только тире. Поскольку предложение заканчивается. Или, в крайнем случае, если оформить как вставную конструкцию, использовать скобки. Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте(нашем любимом).

Comment: @Серж, я посмотрел приведённые вами ссылки. Пример "Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, —  какой ужас!  — и руки бессильно опустились", мне кажется здесь некорректным. Потому как в нём "какой ужас" — самостоятельное выражение, никак не связанное с оборотом "который". В моём вопросе пояснительная часть мне кажется уточнением именно внутри конструкции "который", что особенно напрашивается при замене тире скобками, как верно заметили до меня. С этой позиции, запятая после уточняющей части выглядит уместней.Как вы считаете?

Comment: @Серж, смотрите, если слегка поменять слова местами, то мне кажется, что это становится очевидным: "Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом  — нашем любимом — месте,и постучал"; уточняющее предложение оказывается внутри оборота, а значит, при его положении снаружи, как я понимаю, правила пунктуации остаются теми же самыми. Поправьте меня, если я заблуждаюсь.

Comment: @Третий глаз, в примере:"Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом — нашем любимом — месте,и постучал" - некорректно отрывать "место'' от определения. Получается путаница. В вашем примере ''нашем любимом'' является попутным замечанием. Оно не поясняет место, а попутно сообщает о том, что это место  является ''любимым''. Пояснение - это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.

Comment: @Серж, а если бы предложение было таким: "Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте — выжженном поле, — и постучал"?

Comment: @Серж, тогда бы запятая располагалась перед вторым тире?

Answer (score 0):

Я склоняюсь к тому, что "нашем любимом" - принадлежность придаточного предложения: она относится к одному из его внутренних элементов (как пояснение или уточнение). Требуемое положение закрывающей его запятой более очевидно при заключении вставляемого в скобки.

Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте (нашем любимом), и постучал.

Этот краткий вариант можно распространить так, чтобы скобки были не нужны:

Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте - на нашем любимом месте, и постучал.

Остаётся вопрос, необходимо ли второе тире для замещения убираемого слова "месте". Если поставить его, то придраться трудно, но и без него ясно, что речь о "месте".

**Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте - нашем любимом, - и постучал.**

**Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте - нашем любимом, и постучал.**

Сложнее при несогласованной по падежам и более распространённой вставке. Здесь могут быть основания усмотреть самостоятельный оборот, например:

Я подошёл к дому, который стоял на старом месте, - а это наше любимое место, - и постучал.

Comment: @Alex_ander, а где Вы усмотрели причастный оборот? В примере, который приводит автор, содержится вставная конструкция, которая, к тому же, стоит после придаточного предложения. Придаточное предложение требуется закрыть. Что тут еще неясного?

Comment: В мыслях своих :) "стоявшему на старом месте (нашем любимом)," - а меняет ли это ситуацию с положением места закрытия?
Но исправлю, конечно - спасибо!

Comment: Александр, все-таки в мыслях одно, а на практике - другое. При причастие стоит изменить все предложение: Я подошел к дому, стоявшему на нашем старом, любимом, месте.

Comment: И кстати: так как вы считаете теперь: это принадлежность причастного оборота или же СПП? Сперва вы написали: ''это принадлежность причастного оборота'', а потом изменили на '' СПП''.

Comment: В этом предложении замена слов "который стоял" на "стоявшему" изменяет только название того, чему "нашем любимом" принадлежит. В моих рассуждениях ничего не менялось.

Comment: Однако, сперва Вы написали, что склоняетесь п/о, а потом - к СПП. В том или ином случае запятая будет стоять на старом месте: в 1-ом случае после придаточного предложения, и, если заменить СПП на причастный оборот, - после причастного оборота. (2-ой случай).

Comment: Я ни к чему не склоняюсь. Название оборота имело бы значение, если бы я ссылался на готовое правило с его упоминанием. В данном случае важно только, что тот или иной оборот заканчивается словом "любимом" и запятой после него, а не раньше.